# How to record guitar outdoor and in studio and then sync both perfectly

Tags: guitar, recording, fingerstyle-guitar

Some guys on youtube make very professional videos of themself playing guitar outside, like [Peter Gergely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urIJuFhjNFw) or [Eddie Van Meer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_F4iG5_l0s).

How do they record that? I mean in the second post a user commented:

> *Ramesh lg*: Peter Gergely  bro..  Yu plz make a outdoor video of behind scenes... 
>   Plzzz... How it sounds so clear.. 
>   Everytime i see yur videos i get motivated..
>   Love yu bro...
>
> [...]
>
> *Lucas Izquierdo*: Im pretty sure he goes out records the video and then records the songs indoor in a semi studio, then after that he runs the tracks over and syncs them perfectly!

How to they record two separate pieces and then sync them perfectly, when obviously on their outdoor sessions they do not use a metronom and just play "by feeling"?? Either they must be extremly good in holding the timing when they play solo (I doubt someone can perfectly(!) play 120bpm over many minutes without some reference...), or they use some tricks? (maybe record them outside in bad quality and use this as a reference in studio, or something else?)

Comment: They might record in the studio first then listen to that and mime while recording the video.

Comment: People have been miming to pre-recorded tracks since 1967 [Strawberry Fields, 'first ever' video] - over time, they got better at it.

Comment: You don't even have to mime if you just throw away the audio from the video recording. You just play along with yourself.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You mean the other way around, play along your outdoor recording in the studio?

Comment: You can do it either way. It's just like playing along with a band. You record one of them first. Either one. Then all subsequent recordings/videos you are playing along with the first recording.

Comment: This video might be a hint: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHuLpjyZPPs#t=1m52s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this quite often with my current band - because we accurately track tempo from our drum track, we can interleave studio audio with stage or other audio as needed, giving us some flexibility to have the energy of the live show, the accuracy of our studio work, or extras.

The only things you need to watch for are:

- Initial synchronisation: you can use a clapperboard, or play along to your own audio track
- Playback tempo: make sure your playback is accurate, i.e. Don't use an old tape deck that varies in speed...

Answer (score 2):

My Answer- Pre-record your audio part in any DAW (like reaper ,cubase,garageband) and go outside and shoot your video playing to that pre recorded audio and then in video editor delete the sound from camera and sync up it with the audio

Comment: I believe this is the simplest answer that also applies to most cases. The videos OP linked have pre-recorded audio and the performance is to a playback. To interleave live portions as the accepted answer states you would need recording equipment (microphone, pickup) and possibly a controlled environment (i.e. no fountain in the background that produces noise).

Answer (score 0):

The Peter Gergely video definitely has the sound recorded somewhere else. The ambiance / reverb doesn't sound like being outdoors at all, and there are no microphones or other recording equipment in sight. The Eddie Van Meer one as well.

It's pretty evident when they slap / tap on the guitar, you can hear the room reverberations, which wouldn't happen outdoors..